# Bind Data From Property to Textblock - MVVM Light and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a textblock in WPF which is bound to a property in my ViewModel class. On click of a button I wish to modify the property and expect the same to be reflected in my textblock. I want all these to be done purely using MVVM (MVVMLight). I am using MMVM light and VS 2012.
Challenges- On button click the changes are not being reflected. Though the program execution is going inside the property , changes are not being made.

Please Help !!

Program- View:

```
<Window x:Class="MvvmLight1_Trail.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
    mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
    Height="500"
    Width="500"
    Title="MVVM Light Application"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">



<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">


    <TextBlock FontSize="34"
               Text="{Binding Path=MyText,UpdateSourceTrigger=Default, Mode=TwoWay}"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <Button Width="100" Height="100" Command="{Binding PressCommand}" Margin="198.985,277.537,193.014,92.462" Content="Press Me"/>

</Grid>
```

View Model

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using MvvmLight1_Trail.Model;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;

namespace MvvmLight1_Trail.ViewModel
{

public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{



    public RelayCommand PressCommand { get; private set; }
    Thread t;
    private string _welcomeTitle = string.Empty;


    public string MyText
    {
        get
        {
            return _welcomeTitle;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_welcomeTitle == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _welcomeTitle = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(MyText);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        PressCommand = new RelayCommand(() => MyFunc());
        myfunc();
    }

    private void MyFunc()
    {
        this.MyText = "Hi2";
    }

    private void myfunc()
    {

        this.MyText = "Hello";
        this.MyText = "Hi";

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace

`RaisePropertyChanged(MyText);`

to

`RaisePropertyChanged("MyText");`

PropertyChanged event should be raised on property name and not on property value.

Answer (score 4):

Already answered by @Rohit Vats. You can also call RaisePropertyChanged like, `RaisePropertyChanged( () => MyText)` to ease renaming later.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game but:

in new C# 6 you can also use nameof like this:

```
RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(MyText))
```